# How do I load images instead of LMDB in ssd-caffe

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

There are some questions when I read ssd-caffe code and I really need your help.

1. Native caffe only supports classification, data reading layer is commonly used to read LMDB database and read image for training
2. In order to support the input of multiple labels and input annotation boxes, I decide to use ssd-caffe, which adds an AnnotatedDataLayer layer to the native caffe. This newly added layer can support multiple labels and annotation boxes, but it has limitations. The reason is that the type of data it reads is still lmdb;
3. We now need to read the data of the data set randomly, but according to the query results, lmdb is a B+ tree structure, which can only be read sequentially through the iterator, so we want to change lmdb to read the images directly. However, the direct reading pictures of native caffe do not support multi-labels and annotation boxes. How can I modify the image_data_layers of caffe to support the input of annotation boxes (Can I follow AnnotatedDataLayer's approach to solve the problem)?

Note:

- Modified ssd-caffe source code: https://github.com/eric612/MobileNet-YOLO
- The file path of the newly added annotation box: /MobileNet-YOLO/src/caffe/layers/annotated_data_layer.cpp
- Native caffe file path for reading pictures directly: /MobileNet-YOLO/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data layer** offers the possibility of reading random data from the hard disk asynchronously (it uses 2 threads: in one it reads and in the other it delivers the data to the neural network). Your top blob is made up of the data and the label. Unfortunately, the label is 1-dimensional. To solve this problem it is possible to organize our lmdb database in a special order. Then when we read the data, before delivering it to the neural network, we transform it to adapt it to our problem. Below I show this in an example: First I will write an LMDB database with 10 different images (it is the same image, but we will assume they are different), 10 random bounding boxes and 10 random labels of dimension 3 each one.

**NOTE**: to reproduce the following codes you must have caffe installed. If you only have the caffe folder compiled, then create the folder in **root_caffe/examples/new_folder**, put the code in there and then compile doing **make**.

```
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>
#include "caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h"
#include "caffe/util/db.hpp"
#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace caffe;  
using boost::scoped_ptr;


std::vector<float> generate_random_boxes(const int max_num_bbx){

        std::vector<float> bbx(4*max_num_bbx);

    for(int i = 0; i < max_num_bbx; i++){

       float scale = 500*static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
       float x1 = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
       float y1 = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
       float x2 = x1 + static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
       float y2 = x1 + static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
       bbx[i*4] = scale*x1;
       bbx[i*4 + 1] = scale*y1;
       bbx[i*4 + 2] = scale*x2;
       bbx[i*4 + 3] = scale*y2;

    }

    return bbx;
}

std::vector<float> generate_random_labels(const int dim_label, const int max_num_bbx){

        std::vector<float> labels(dim_label*max_num_bbx);

    for(int i = 0; i < max_num_bbx; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < dim_label; j++){

          labels[dim_label*i + j] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);

           }    
    }

    return labels;
}


int main(){

  const std::string root_path = "/path/for/test/";  
  const std::string path_lmdb = root_path + "lmdb";
  std::string rm_lmdb = std::string("rm -rf ") + path_lmdb.c_str(); 
  system(rm_lmdb.c_str());
  scoped_ptr<db::DB> db(db::GetDB("lmdb"));
  db->Open(path_lmdb, db::NEW);
  scoped_ptr<db::Transaction> txn(db->NewTransaction());


  int n = 10;
  int max_num_bbx = 7;
  int dim_label = 3;
  cv::Mat aux_img = cv::imread(root_path + "image.jpg");
  int rows = aux_img.rows;
  int cols = aux_img.cols;

  std::vector<cv::Mat> vec_img(n);
  std::vector< std::vector<float> > vec_bbx(n);
  std::vector< std::vector<float> > vec_label(n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

     vec_img[i] = aux_img.clone();  
     vec_bbx[i] = generate_random_boxes(max_num_bbx);
     vec_label[i] = generate_random_labels(dim_label, max_num_bbx);

  }

  for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){

     int sz = 3*rows*cols + 4*max_num_bbx + dim_label*max_num_bbx; 

     Datum datum;
     datum.set_label(0); //no used
     datum.set_channels(1);
     datum.set_height(1);
     datum.set_width(sz);

     google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>* datumFloatData = datum.mutable_float_data(); 

     //store images
     cv::Mat img = vec_img[i];
     for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){ //BGR
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){ 
           for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){ 

              cv::Vec3b pixel = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(r, c);
              datumFloatData->Add(float(pixel[d]));

           }
        }
     }


    //store bounding-boxes
    std::vector<float>& bbx = vec_bbx[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < 4*max_num_bbx; j++)
       datumFloatData->Add(bbx[j]);     

    //store labels
    std::vector<float>& label = vec_label[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < dim_label*max_num_bbx; j++)
       datumFloatData->Add(label[j]);     


    //store lmdb
    std::string key_str = caffe::format_int(i);
    std::string out;
    CHECK(datum.SerializeToString(&out));
    txn->Put(key_str, out);
    txn->Commit();
    txn.reset(db->NewTransaction());
    std::cout<<"save data: "<<i<<std::endl;


  }

 return 0;

}
```

then in folder **"/path/for/test"** we will have a folder called **lmdb** that contains our database. Now we must read the data and organize it in the desired order. For this I will use a **Slice** layer, which allows dividing an input bottom data into multiple tops. Thus, the input data made up of the batch of images, bounding boxes and labels will be divided into 5 top blobs: img_b, img_g, img_r, bbx, labels.

```
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>

#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace caffe;  
using boost::scoped_ptr;

int main(){


  const std::string root_path = "/path/for/test/";
  const std::string path_lmdb = root_path + "lmdb";


  //parameters used to store lmdb data base  
  int n = 10;
  int max_num_bbx = 7;
  int dim_label = 3;
  cv::Mat aux_img = cv::imread(root_path + "image.jpg");
  int rows = aux_img.rows;
  int cols = aux_img.cols;


  //here we build the network input

  NetParameter net_param;

  LayerParameter* db_layer_param = net_param.add_layer();
  db_layer_param->set_name("data");
  db_layer_param->set_type("Data");
  DataParameter* db_data_param = db_layer_param->mutable_data_param();

  db_data_param->set_batch_size(2);
  db_data_param->set_prefetch(3);


  db_data_param->set_source(path_lmdb);
  db_data_param->set_backend(DataParameter_DB_LMDB); 


  db_layer_param->add_top("data"); 

  LayerParameter* slice_layer_param = net_param.add_layer();
  slice_layer_param->set_name("slice");
  slice_layer_param->set_type("Slice");
  slice_layer_param->mutable_slice_param()->set_axis(3);//starting B
  slice_layer_param->mutable_slice_param()->add_slice_point(rows*cols);//starting G
  slice_layer_param->mutable_slice_param()->add_slice_point(2*rows*cols);//starting R
  slice_layer_param->mutable_slice_param()->add_slice_point(3*rows*cols);//starting bbx
  slice_layer_param->mutable_slice_param()->add_slice_point(3*rows*cols + 4*max_num_bbx);//starting labels


  slice_layer_param->add_bottom("data");

  slice_layer_param->add_top("img_b"); 
  slice_layer_param->add_top("img_g");
  slice_layer_param->add_top("img_r");
  slice_layer_param->add_top("bbx");
  slice_layer_param->add_top("labels");


  //NOTE: you must add the additional layers of your model
  /*
  . 
  .
  .
  .
  */



  //here we store and load the model
  //NOTE:In this example is not necessary to store the model in prototxt file
  const std::string net_file = root_path + "model.prototxt";
  Net<float> net(net_param);
  WriteProtoToTextFile(net_param,net_file); 




  //here we make forward in order to read our data
  net.Forward();



  /*Note that in this example we read 2 images, but then we will only show the first*/

  //read first image 
  boost::shared_ptr< Blob< float > > img_b = net.blob_by_name("img_b");
  boost::shared_ptr< Blob< float > > img_g = net.blob_by_name("img_g");
  boost::shared_ptr< Blob< float > > img_r = net.blob_by_name("img_r");

  cv::Mat img(rows,cols,CV_8UC3); 

  for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
      for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){

      img.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[0] = (uchar) img_b->cpu_data()[r*cols + c];   
      img.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[1] = (uchar) img_g->cpu_data()[r*cols + c]; 
      img.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[2] = (uchar) img_r->cpu_data()[r*cols + c];
      }
  }



  //read bounding boxes
  boost::shared_ptr< Blob< float > > bbx = net.blob_by_name("bbx");

  for(int i = 0; i < max_num_bbx; i++){

     float x1 = bbx->cpu_data()[4*i];
     float y1 = bbx->cpu_data()[4*i + 1];
     float x2 = bbx->cpu_data()[4*i + 2];
     float y2 = bbx->cpu_data()[4*i + 3];

     cv::Point pt1(y1, x1);
     cv::Point pt2(y2, x2);
     cv::rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));

  }


 //read labels
 boost::shared_ptr< Blob< float > > labels = net.blob_by_name("labels");

 std::cout<<"labels: "<<std::endl; 
 for(int i = 0; i < max_num_bbx; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < dim_label; j++){

     std::cout<<labels->cpu_data()[i*dim_label + j]<<" ";

    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
 }


 cv::imshow("img", img);
 cv::waitKey(0);

 return 0;

}
```

The output generated is as follows:

[image]

The prototxt generated with WriteProtoToTextFile (net_param, net_file) by the **Data** and **Slice layers** is as follows:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  data_param {
    source: "/path/for/test/lmdb"
    batch_size: 2
    backend: LMDB
    prefetch: 3
  }
}
layer {
  name: "slice"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "img_b"
  top: "img_g"
  top: "img_r"
  top: "bbx"
  top: "labels"
  slice_param {
    slice_point: 344000
    slice_point: 688000
    slice_point: 1032000
    slice_point: 1032028
    axis: 3
  }
}
```

After the **Slice layer**, you may need to add additional **Reshape layers** to adapt the data to the subsequent layers.